# Python how to handle split when string is equal to None?

Tags: string, python-3.x, split

```
def SetLength(passedString):
    wordlength = passedString.split()
    print(passedString)
    print(len(wordlength))

SetLength("Python code to count the words")
```

This is my code to count the word in a string now this is working fine, but when I set

```
str = None

SetLength(str)
```

this shows an error like this

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Can anyone please helping me in this?

Comment: Why would you pass `None` into `SetLength` if it expects a string?

Comment: i am calling the string object from the json file, if sometimes json have None type in string, my code has to be handle that situation

Comment: Sorry, The situation is that input is not sure it can be Null (None) and my code should not crash and it should return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be to add an if:

```
...
if not passedString:
    passedString = ""
...
```

Of course, this could also be done before calling `SetLength()`, so that you don't call `SetLength()` in case `passedString` is None.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should specify the exact functionality of SetLength(). What's it supposed to do when called with argument None?

If it's supposed to handle this, change the implementation accordingly.

If None is not allowed, change the calling code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The error is perfectly valid.

You cannot call .split on a None object since it doesn't have that attribute.

You need to do one of two things here:

1. You can check if the object is "truthy":

   i.e.:

   ```
   def SetLength(passedString):
       if passedString:
           wordlength = passedString.split()
           return len(wordlength)

       # if it's none, it will come here...
       # you probably want to return 0 as the length of words at that point
       return 0
   ```

   Note: This will also return 0 for an empty string ""; which is expected
2. You can use "isinstance" to make sure the object is a string:

   i.e.:

   ```
   def SetLength(passedString):
       if isinstance(passedString, str):
           wordlength = passedString.split()
           return len(wordlength)

       # if it's none, it will come here...
       # you probably want to return 0 as the length of words at that point
       return 0
   ```

Comment: Thanks, now if we are not sure about input type , like it can be object , it can be dictionary , it can be integer.So we check type and it not string we type cast it.

Comment: Well, if it's a dictionary, then what will it look like?
you'll need knowledge about the dictionary structure to convert it to a string..
If it's an integer, the length of words is always going to be 1

if isinstance(passedString, int):
    return 1

This is very messy. 
If you're not sure that you're getting either a string or None, then maybe you should revisit what you're trying to achieve...
Some more insight into that might help.

Comment: the problem is i am calling a object from outside json, in this cases i am not sure , what type of data is there, its maybe an string, integer and None also,  your code helping me to handle None, thank you very much for that